# How to avoid writing same http subscribe blocks for different components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Let's assume that there is a service will be used for http request calls.And two different components(could be more than two) which will send same request by using same observables via this service.After getting result that should be assigned to global variable(Components have not relationship like parent-child or child-parent).Below I wrote same code block for all components.Is there any better way to write this function once and call by returning same value?

**Service**

```
  getStudents() {
    const requestUrl = this.apiUrl + 'students/';
    return this.httpClient.get(requestUrl);
  }
```

**Component1**

```
  studentList:Student[]=[];
  getStudents.subscribe((students:Student[])=>{
      this.studentList=students;
      //Some operations
  })
```

**Component2**

```
  studentList:Student[]=[];
  getStudents.subscribe((students:Student[])=>{
       //Some operations 
  this.studentList=students;
  })
```

Comment: You can refactor the anonymous function you're passing to `.subscribe()` into a named one and simply pass the function's name instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a fan of global state, but if you want to maintain the same list of students across components using global state, then that state may as well live in the service (Rather than existing in each component separately)

So, for example:

#### Service

```ts
studentList:Student[] = [];

setStudents(students:Student[]) {
  this.studentList = students;
  // Operations involved with setting students
}

updateStudents() {
  const requestUrl = this.apiUrl + 'students/';
  return this.httpClient.get(requestUrl).pipe(
    tap(this.setStudents)
  );
}
```

#### Component

```ts
ngOnInit(){
  this.service.updateStudents().subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Im not fan too.But I need them to iterate over ngFor

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek Angular's Async Pipe solves that problem admirably :). If a component doesn't render using internal state, you can turn off change detection for that component. Across a whole project, that can end up boosting performance. It's not a must-have, but hey.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an Observable inside your service,

```
studentsReceived:Subject = new Subject();
```

on success of getStundent() you can emit next value of studentsReceived.

Now you can subscribe to the studentsReceived inside your components, after the successful API call you will be notified of each of the subscribed components.

```
studentRecived.subscribe(data=>{ // do some code })
```

You must call this getStudent() on some higher component like AppComponent.

Comment: but in this way I won't be able to send request anytime component visited.I'd like to send request on each component's onInit

Comment: Then you can keep a private variable in your service and update that inside the success callback.
Create one getter to access that variable in the component in getter you can check is variable have value if not then you can call the `getStudent()` again.

Answer (score 0):

2 Important things here:

```
1) If you dont want to repeat the same block of code, then create a method in the service file, 
and call it in the component. Something like this: 

SERVICE: 

makeSubcription(componentVariableName) {
  this.yourObservable.subcribe(subscribedValue => {
     componentVariableName = subscribedValue;
  })
}

In your Component, you can do this: 

yourComponentMethod() {
  this.service.makeSubscription(this.studentLists);
}


************

2) If you dont want to make a service call too many times, what you can do is, 
use Behavior Subject and try to store the values, so that you are subscribing to the observable and not the actual API call. Something like this: 


private initialValuesForObservable: YourObjectModel = {}; // or null;

private observableSource: BehaviorSubject<YourObjectModel> = 
  new BehaviorSubject<YourObjectModel>(this.initialValuesForObservable);

public subscribableObservable: Observable<YourObjectModel> = 
  this.observableSource.asObservable();


setObservableValue(data: YourObjectModel) {
  this.observableSource.next(data);
}

getObservableData() {
  return this.subscribableObservable;
}



In your COMPONENT; 

this.service.getObservableData().subscribe(latestObservableData => {
  this.schoolList = latestObservableData;
});
```